# Add variable as a result in a query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Rails 4.2.5, PostgreSQL 9.4+

I have a DailyMetric table.  As the name implies, it has daily metrics for each associate.  I am trying to summarize these metrics into various periods, such as week to date, last week, month to date, etc.  The query I have pulls the selected records but I want to summarize the records within the period, but the period is an external variable to the table.  The query, as it stands, is:

```
records = DailyMetric.
  where('metrics_date >= ? AND metrics_date <= ?', period.first, period.last).
  select("associate_logon as logon, metrics_date as logon_date,
    sum((metrics #>> '{\"Login\"}')::NUMERIC) as total_logons").
  group('associate_logon, metrics_date')
```

The result, as of today, is that I get records for each associate for Monday and Tuesday for week to date where the week starts on Monday.  Instead of group using metrics_date, I would like to group using period.

Can I get the desired result by modifying the query or do I have to run such a summary externally myself?  I can do the external summary, if needed.  I would just like to know if I can do it within the query.

FWIW and for completeness, the statistics, such as Login, are stored in PostgreSQL using JSONB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote the query without the group clause and am handling myself.  In the end, the group just wasn't going to do what I needed done.  Thanks.